# A function which dynamically creates a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d

I want to create a dynamic 2d array in a separate function. The size of the array will be determined at runtime.

Pass an array directly:

```
  void foo(int **arr,int width,int height)
        {
        arr=new int*[width];
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
        {
        arr[i]=new int[height];
        }
        //fill...
        }
    ...
    int** array;
    foo(array)
```

doesn't seem to work

Pass an array via a pointer

```
  void foo(int ***arr,int width,int height)
        {
        *arr=new int*[width];
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
        {
        *arr[i]=new int[height];
        }
        //fill...
        }
    ...
    int **array;
    foo(&array)
```

doesnt seem to work either

How do I do that?

Comment: Use `std::vector`, nothing more to say.

Comment: Please avoid this and use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. You need to pass a triple pointer for this to work.

Comment: If you're going to go this route, you could do it a [little more optimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have to create 2d arrays this way (with an `int**`).

Instead of trying to pass pointers, return the value that denotes the 2d array.

Second, your code had a bug in that you were looping over the `height` when you should be looping over the `width`.  Your code would have gone into undefined behavior if `height > width`.

Third, I don't know if you meant `width` to be the first dimension or `height` to be the first dimension, so let's assume that what you wrote is what you meant, i.e. `width` is the first dimension and `height` is the inner dimension.

```
int **foo(int width, int height)
{
    int **arr = new int*[width];
    for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
       arr[i]=new int[height];
    return arr;
}
//....
int width = 10, height = 10;
int** array = foo(width, height);
```

Then you have to write code to delete the allocated data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
   delete [] array [i];
delete [] array;
```

---

Now having said the above, and the above should work, a more optimal version is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048), where the data is one contiguous block instead of separate allocated blocks.  This reduces the number of times `new[]` and `delete []` would need to be called.

Comment: Thank you for help, all of the answers seem to work but yours is even better than what I wanted to achieve (1 parameter less, same effect)

Answer (score 2):

I think that your "problem" is caused by ignoring [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Second code you posted seems to have mistake on line with:

```
*arr[i]=new int[height];
```

which should be

```
(*arr)[i]=new int[height];
```

---

Also, as other pointed out, working with *raw* pointers could sometimes be pretty evil (like in your example with *Pointer to Pointer to Pointer*), raw pointers could also cause some problems with *memory leaks*, *dangling pointers*,*etc*. Use something "more practical" like `std::vector` or some of the other STL containers.

(Note: By term "STL", I mean part of Standard library based on STL)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, multidimensional arrays should never, *never* be created like this. You should be using a single array wrapped in an object that provides row, column, table, etc. access using the `operator()` function.

You should also never, *never* be using raw pointers (except in weird, extenuating circumstances) which is why I'm using STL's `std::vector` class to implement your code.

```
class array_2d {
public:
    array_2d(size_t width, size_t height) :
    width(width),
    height(height),
    _array(width * height)
    {}

    int & operator()(size_t x, size_t y) {
        return _array[y * width + x];
    }

    const int & operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const {
        return _array[y * width + x];
    }

    std::pair<size_t, size_t> get_size() const {
        return std::make_pair<size_t, size_t>(width, height);
    }
private:
    size_t width, height;
    std::vector<int> _array;
};

int main() {
    array_2d my_array(5,5);
    my_array(3,3) = 7;
    std::cout << my_array(3,3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

====

```
7
```

There's a lot of stuff I didn't include (and the code would be significantly more complex if you were to implement this as a raw pointer) but this is a far superior way to write a 2-dimensional (or more dimensions, if you need it) array.